# How can I restore control of my computer to the BIOS from grub?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I tried to use Parted Magic (unsuccessfully) and now when I try to boot I get the message:

error: unknown filesystem.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>

When I go into the BIOS to override the HDD from which to boot I still get that message.

I can no longer boot into my Windows partition.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have changed the partition id of some of your partitions.

try booting form an ubuntu live cd , get a terminal up and run these commands:

```
sudo fdisk

<possible password prompt here>

l
```

this will print a list of filesystems.

use t to change the types (a list of the codes will be printed)

use l to check your changes where ok

use w to write the changes when you are happy with them

then reboot

Comment: just run `update-grub`

Comment: make sure you check your filesystems still make sense before updating grub

Comment: If he is able to boot anything, they most probably are ok. If you change your partition table _without_ running `update-grub` you will __most probably fail to boot__.